# How to install Pygame in PyCharm with error "no such option: --build-dir"

Tags: python, pygame, pycharm

I have created a PyCharm project, updated pip to 22.0.4 and updated setuptools to 62.0.0 (both the latest versions). When I go to the project settings>Project Interpreter>Install and attempt to install pygame, it throws the following error:

```
Executed command: pip install pygame

Error occured: Non-zero exit code (2)

Proposed solution: Try to run this command from the system terminal. Make sure that you use the correct version of 'pip' installed for your Python interpreter located at 'C:\Users\geema\PycharmProjects\smallgame\venv\Scripts\python.exe'.

Usage:   
  C:\Users\geema\PycharmProjects\smallgame\venv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install [options] <requirement specifier> [package-index-options] ...

  C:\Users\geema\PycharmProjects\smallgame\venv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install [options] -r <requirements file> [package-index-options] ...

  C:\Users\geema\PycharmProjects\smallgame\venv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install [options] [-e] <vcs project url> ...

  C:\Users\geema\PycharmProjects\smallgame\venv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install [options] [-e] <local project path> ...

  C:\Users\geema\PycharmProjects\smallgame\venv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install [options] <archive url/path> ...

no such option: --build-dir
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you try the proposed solution? What happened?

Comment: Yes, I have tried running 'pip install pygame', 'pip3 install pygame' in the terminal and it didn't work. I also have ensured that the latest version of pip is installed, and can see that pip is up to date in the project interpreter settings.

Comment: "I have tried running 'pip install pygame', 'pip3 install pygame' in the terminal and it didn't work" - Did it give the same error, another one or none at all? Does the terminal says that pygame is installed, but can't you use it in pycharm? Can you import pygame in the python console?

Comment: @The_spider After running 'install pygame' it throws the error:
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\geema\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6vyhw2v9\pygame\
Python is not installed, it is clear as I can go to the project settings and see that pygame isn't there. I do not understand what you mean by 'importing pygame in the python console.'

Comment: "Python is not installed" - Do you mean pygame instead of python?

Comment: To go to the python console, search for a progrom named python and open it. Then type "import pygame" and press enter. It should look like this: https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/Content/images/python/python-shell.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to simply use the interpreter from another project on my current one, and the interpreter has Pygame on it. I am still not sure as to why the error occurred.